# Getting content from external sources via wire

Tags: streaming

I keep my phone beside me when sleeping at night. I've set it to automatically enable airplane mode for it to stay totally quiet, charge faster and remain cool. But I sometimes hook it up with my speakers at bed to play an audio book, for example, but many of them are quite large.

Here's the issue. It's tedious to delete and replace content on my phone, but I don't want to enable any wireless connection. How can I access media on my local home network? Basically, any wired external media source would do.

Comment: I believe there can be a more appropriate title and tag, but I'll leave it for others to come up with that.

Comment: @Firelord Neither could I think of a better title.